# How to name undo and redo actions in a simple Core Data app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I'm currently trying to get used to programming Apps on OS X with Obj-C and cocoa and stumbled upon a small question in core data. My application works so far, except I would like to name the edit and undo menu items (like "undo new x" or "undo edit name" and so on).

I've googled, but so far come up with no solution. I've read about a .strings file, but I don't think, that this file gives me the freedom I want to name my undo and redo items.

I know how to do it without core data. But I don't know where and what I should edit to do this with core data.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the accepted answer is a link-only answer to a site which is no longer available.  Maybe the Wayback Machine could be used, but as it stands, the answer is unhelpful, and therefore this question is unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [this article](http://homepage.mac.com/tom_zepko/cocoa/topics/undo-redo.html) might be of help. (404 as of 2014-05-15.)

---

Wayback Machine URL:

- [Undo/Redo In Controls](http://web.archive.org/web/20110831134903/http://homepage.mac.com/tom_zepko/cocoa/topics/undo-redo.html)

Comment: You still remember what was in this article? Because the link is rotten by now :)

Comment: This is a prime example of why 'link-only' answers are no help; the link goes away and people have no idea what it used to contain.